# PHP DOM parsing text between <hr> tags

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I am trying to parse some HTML to get the text between two `<hr>` tags using DOM with PHP but I don't get any output when I pass in `hr` into `getElementsByTagName`:

```
<?php 
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML("<hr>Text<hr>");
    $hr = $dom->getElementsByTagName("hr");
    for ($i=0; $i<$hr->length; $i++) {
        echo "[". $i . "]" . $hr->item($i)->nodeValue . "</br>";
    }
?>
```

When I run this code, it doesn't output anything however, if I change `"hr"` to `"*"` then it outputs:

```
[0]Text
[1]Text
[2]
[3]
```

(Why four lines of results?)

I run this code on a webserver which has PHP version 7.1.3 running. I can't use functions such as `file_get_html` or `str_get_html` because it returns an error about Undefined call to function ...

Why doesn't the `hr` tag produce results?

Comment: You have two empty `<hr>` elements. How would they have a `nodeValue`?

Comment: Forgot to mention that if add add </hr> , it gives me an error and I still don't get value:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : hr in Entity, line: 1. Is regex the only way to get the value between the tags then?

Comment: That happens, because the `<hr>` can't have any content: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps what you're looking for is the contents of the text node *between* two `<hr>` elements? In that case we go looking for siblings with an XPath expression:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("Some text<hr>The text<hr>Other text");
$xp = new DomXPath($dom);
$result = $xp->query("//text()[(preceding-sibling::hr and following-sibling::hr)]");
foreach ($result as $i=>$node) {
    echo "[$i]$node->textContent<br/>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens, because the `<hr>` has no child nodes (text are also childs).
To get the text between the `<hr>` nodes, you have to iterate over all nodes on the same level and check if the current node is a text node (nodeType == 3), the previous sibling must be a `HR` node and the next sibling must be a `HR` node too.

```
<?php 
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML("<hr>Text<hr>");

    foreach ($dom->childNodes as $childNode) {
        if (3 !== $childNode->nodeType) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!$childNode->previousSibling || ('HR' !== $childNode->previousSibling->nodeName)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!$childNode->nextSibling || ('HR' !== $childNode->nextSibling->nodeName)) {
            continue;
        }

        echo "{$childNode->nodeValue}\n";
    }
```

But if you want to get *anything* between the `hr` nodes it will be more complicated.